# How to use custom priority fee when sending solana transactions using solana.py

Tags: transactions, python, devnet, solana-py, solana.py

This is my current code.

**CODE:**

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.transaction import Transaction
from solana.system_program import TransferParams, transfer

LAMPORT_PER_SOL = 1000000000

client = Client(devnetrpc)

transaction = Transaction().add(transfer(TransferParams(
    from_pubkey=sender.public_key,
    to_pubkey=receiver.public_key,
    lamports=int(0.01*LAMPORT_PER_SOL))
))

response = client.send_transaction(transaction, sender)
print (response)
send_signature = response["result"]
status = client.confirm_transaction(send_signature)
print (status)
```

This will send a legacy transaction. I want to add priority fee to the transaction. Any sample code is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the `compute_budget` module directly from the solders library: https://kevinheavey.github.io/solders/api_reference/compute_budget.html

Here's an example of how to add it to your transaction:

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.transaction import Transaction
from solana.system_program import TransferParams, transfer
from solders.compute_budget import set_compute_unit_price

LAMPORT_PER_SOL = 1000000000

client = Client(devnetrpc)

transaction = Transaction().add(set_compute_unit_price(1_000)).add(transfer(TransferParams(
    from_pubkey=sender.public_key,
    to_pubkey=receiver.public_key,
    lamports=int(0.01*LAMPORT_PER_SOL))
))
```

Comment: I was looking for the same solution, but the example above throws error "solders.SignerError: not enough signers"

Comment: There's a bug somewhere, I haven't had the chance to look into it yet, but here's a workaround: https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/11568/84

Answer (score 2):

fixed 'not engouh signers' error

```
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solders.system_program import TransferParams, transfer
from solders.compute_budget import set_compute_unit_limit, 
set_compute_unit_price

transaction = (
    Transaction(fee_payer=sender.pubkey(), recent_blockhash=recent_blockhash)
    .add(set_compute_unit_price(transfer_fee))
    .add(
        transfer(
            TransferParams(
                from_pubkey=sender.pubkey(),
                to_pubkey=Pubkey.from_string(receiver_address),
                lamports=amount,
            )
        )
    )
)
result = solana_client.send_transaction(
    transaction,
    sender,
    opts=TxOpts(preflight_commitment=Processed),
)
```

specifying 'fee_payer' when initializing Transaction() fixed the problem for me