# Not enough signers when setting compute units

Tags: python, solana-py, priority-fees

Getting this error when trying to set priority fee

```
solders.SignerError: not enough signers
```

Python 3.10.2

Solders 0.18.1

Solana 0.30.2

Code example is just following the solana cookbook:

```
...

transaction = Transaction()
transaction.add(set_compute_unit_limit(1_000_000))
transaction.add(set_compute_unit_price(1_000))
transaction.add(transfer(TransferParams(
    from_pubkey=sender.pubkey(),
    to_pubkey=receiver.pubkey(),
    lamports=int(0.001*LAMPORT_PER_SOL))
    ))

signature = client.send_transaction(transaction, sender)
```

Error does not appear when removing the priority fee instructions.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug, but it's hard to see exactly where. Somewhere, the logic is failing to identify the fee payer for the transaction to be the `from_pubkey` in your transfer.

Here are a couple of workarounds:

- set the fee payer by hand

```
transaction = Transaction()
transaction.fee_payer = sender.pubkey()
transaction.add(set_compute_unit_limit(1_000_000))
transaction.add(set_compute_unit_price(1_000))
transaction.add(transfer(TransferParams(
    from_pubkey=sender.pubkey(),
    to_pubkey=receiver.pubkey(),
    lamports=int(0.001*LAMPORT_PER_SOL))
    ))

signature = client.send_transaction(transaction, sender)
```

- add the compute budget instructions at the end

```
transaction = Transaction()
transaction.add(transfer(TransferParams(
    from_pubkey=sender.pubkey(),
    to_pubkey=receiver.pubkey(),
    lamports=int(0.001*LAMPORT_PER_SOL))
    ))
transaction.add(set_compute_unit_limit(1_000_000))
transaction.add(set_compute_unit_price(1_000))

signature = client.send_transaction(transaction, sender)
```